# Jquery open link in a new window

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I am binding json list to a div to make it look like a table. Click of each item in table takes to its description page through jquery redirection. But after binding I do not see the option to right click on item and open in new tab or window. I am unable to use control + click on item. How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: are u impeding the data in an "anchor" node?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular link instead of a JavaScript function.